# Почему без console.log функция выполнятся гораздо быстрее?

Tags: javascript

Попытался сваять мини-benchmark для тестов мини-велосипедов, которые я порой пишу, когда мне лень искать готовое решение. Столкнулся со странностью - если не выводить в консоль вывод тестируемой функции, то время выполнения уменьшается во много раз. Такое ощущение, как будто тестируемая функция вообще не выполняется, если её не консолить. Почему так происходит? Неужели console.log - настолько тяжелая функция?

```js
function benchmark(action,times){
    var start=Date.now();
    for(var i=0;i<times;i++)action();
    return Date.now()-start;
}
document.getElementById('test_function').onclick=function test_function(){
    //var t=eval('(function(){'+document.getElementById('code').value+'})');
    var action=new Function(document.getElementById('code').value);
    var times=+document.getElementById('times').value||1;
    var result=benchmark(action,times);
    document.getElementById('output').value+='Выполнено '+times+' раз за '+result+' ms\n';
}
```

```css
textarea{
    width:400px;
    height:130px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="code">
var t1=[
 'c1=oldvalue;sdfsdssa=old;',
 'c2=oldvalue;sdfsdds=old;',
]
var t2=[
 'c2=update;sdfsd=fsffffa;',
 'c3=append;sdfsd2=f;'
]
function extend_cookie_array(cookies,updates){
 parsed={}
 cookies.forEach(function(cookie){
  var t=cookie.split(';');
  var foobar=t[0].split('=');
  parsed[foobar[0]]={
   value:foobar[1],
   over:t.slice(1,t.length),
  }
 });
 updates.forEach(function(update){
  var t=update.split(';');
  var foobar=t[0].split('=');
  parsed[foobar[0]]={
   value:foobar[1],
   over:t.slice(1,t.length)
  }
 });
 var res=[];
 for(var key in parsed){
  parsed[key].over.unshift(key+'='+parsed[key].value);
  res.push(parsed[key].over.join(';'));
 }
 return res;
}
var result=extend_cookie_array(t1,t2);
//Раскомментируйте это и увидите разницу
//console.log(result);
</textarea><br/>
<textarea id="output"></textarea><br/>
<input type="text" id="times" value="10000" />
<button id="test_function">Go</button>
```

Comment: Настолько неоптимизируемая, и да - тяжелая. Это же вставка в dom консоли. Копите массив и выводите потом, это быстрее будет

Comment: Используйте логгеры. Они примерно для того и существуют. http://log4javascript.org/ вот первый попавший под руку пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что по сути своей console.* является чисто дебаговой функцией. Долго потому что приходится проводить кучу операций чтобы вывести данные в консоль.  Вообще на время её выполнения можете даже не смотреть, ведь в продакшен версии всё равно нужно **обязательно** отключать (комментировать или удалять) все обращения к console.* иначе может падать скрипт. Так например в ие до не помню уже какой версии если не открыта дебаговая консоль, а в коде есть console.log например, то на этом месте произойдет ексепшен, из-за обращения к несуществующей переменной.

Comment: До 9 если мне не изменяет память. В 8м точно падает

Comment: Можно еще так делать: `if ( ! DEBUG ) { window.console={log:function(){}, info:function(){}, ... } };` где `DEBUG` это глобальная переменная включаемая при отладке.

Comment: Можно, но лишние такты :) я не люблю когда в коде есть лишние не используемые куски. Тем более что дебаг нужен только доя отлова ошибок. Да и глобальные переменные в принципе плохо. Легко любой скрипт может заменить.